# Performing operations on column with nan's without removing them

Tags: python, pandas, nan, method-chaining

I currently have a data frame like so:

| treated | control |
| --- | --- |
| 9.5 | 9.6 |
| 10 | 5 |
| 6 | 0 |
| 6 | 6 |

I want to apply get a log 2 ratio between treated and control i.e `log2(treated/control)`. However, the `math.log2()` ratio breaks, due to 0 values in the control column (a zero division). Ideally, I would like to get the log 2 ratio using method chaining, e.g a `df.assign()` and simply put nan's where it is not possible, like so:

| treated | control | log_2_ratio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9.5 | 9.6 | -0.00454 |
| 10 | 5 | 0.301 |
| 6 | 0 | nan |
| 6 | 6 | 0 |

I have managed to do this in an extremely round-about way, where I have:

- made a column `ratio` which is `treated/control`
- done `new_df = df.dropna()` on this dataframe
- applied the log 2 ratio to this.
- Left joined it back to it's the original df.

As always, any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: Is there any particular reason for `nan`? it seems `inf` is a better choice and that falls out naturally if you stick to pandas and numpy operations instead of going to the python math.log2 function.

Comment: @tdelaney I guess it depends what you want to do with the data. `inf` is not very practical for a plot for example

Comment: @tdelaney, yep mozway guessed right, the inf values where throwing off my downstream plots!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the `inf` with `nan`:

```
df.assign(log_2_ratio=np.log2(df['treated'].div(df['control'])).replace(np.inf, np.nan))
```

Output:

```
   treated  control  log_2_ratio
0      9.5      9.6    -0.015107
1     10.0      5.0     1.000000
2      6.0      0.0          NaN
3      6.0      6.0     0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid subsequent replacement you may go through an explicit condition (bearing in mind that multiplication/division operation with zero always result in `0`).

```
df.assign(log_2_ratio=lambda x: np.where(x.treated * x.control, np.log2(x.treated/x.control), np.nan))
```

---

```
Out[22]: 
   treated  control  log_2_ratio
0      9.5      9.6    -0.015107
1     10.0      5.0     1.000000
2      6.0      0.0          NaN
3      6.0      6.0     0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Stick with the numpy log functions and you'll get an `inf` in the cells where the divide doesn't work. That seems like a better choice than `nan` anyway.

```
>>> df["log_2_ratio"] = np.log2(df.treated/df.control)
>>> df
   treated  control  log_2_ratio
0      9.5      9.6    -0.015107
1     10.0      5.0     1.000000
2      6.0      0.0          inf
3      6.0      6.0     0.000000
```